# WYSIWYG editor that supports Bootstrap

Tags: wysiwyg, bootstrap

I am developing a totally dynamic web app using **PHP CI**. It has dynamic pages and menus etc., everything is dynamic.

Now what I want is a plugin that supports Bootstrap columns structure completely, like take an example of visual composer in WordPress, it gives you the features like making columns and arranging data. I don't want a full scale plugin like visual composer, but still it should have features like adding columns.

I previously used tinyMCE for a project but it only gives you some basic functionalities like font, text sizes etc.

I am willing to buy a plugin if it suits my requirements. Can anybody recommend a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You try the following:

1. [Summernote](http://summernote.org/)
2. [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/)

They are both open source and on Github. Summernote looks like it is still actively being worked on.

Comment: but still summernote doesnot have a feature of using column structure that is what i am looking for

Comment: Sounds like you need a site builder, not a WYSIWYG. I don't think most WYSIWYG would do something like this.